# How to extract the values from a Json Array in ballerina 0.982.0

Tags: javascript, json, ballerina

I receive a query result from a database as [{"id":}]. When I try to capture this 'id' value as follows it returns a null.

```js
var getClientIdResult=eaDBEndpoint->select(QUERY_GET_CLIENT_ID,(),accountId);
match getClientIdResult {
    table queryResult => {
        match <json>queryResult{
            json jsonResult => {
                clientId=check<int> jsonResult["id"];

            } error e => return e;
        }
    } error e => return e;
}
```

I suppose this cause because of the JSON result comes as a JSON array and the code does not capture the 'id' value inside the JSON object.

Any suggestions regarding how to capture the 'id' value will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a JSON array, you have to access it with the index and then you can pick the element of the picked JSON with the key.

**Example**: This pick the initial JSON of the JSON array and get the *id* of it. `jsonResult[0].id`

```
var getClientIdResult = eaDBEndpoint->select(QUERY_GET_CLIENT_ID,(),accountId);
match getClientIdResult {
    table queryResult => {
        match <json>queryResult {
            json jsonResult => {
                clientId = check <int>jsonResult[0].id;
            }
            error e => return e;
        }
    }
    error e => return e;
}
```

Since it returns error if it occurred you can simply use `check` as follows:

```
var getClientIdResult = eaDBEndpoint->select(QUERY_GET_CLIENT_ID,(),accountId);
table queryResult = check <table>getClientIdResult;
json jsonResult = check <json>queryResult;
clientId = check <int>jsonResult[0].id;
```

---

Please refer [1] for more examples on how to use JSON arrays.

[1] https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/json-arrays.html

Comment: @idclakmal Getting an error as 'error:... mismatched input '.'. expecting '=>'' for the line 'json jsonResult.getJsonArray()=>{'.

Comment: @NipunaDilhara Updated the code. Can you please check now.

Comment: @idclakmal The answer works fine. Thanks for the help.